# Is there any way to `tsc -w` multiple packages into their own `dist` folder?

Tags: typescript

## Problem

I am using a lerna packages layout:

```
packages
    groupA
        packageA
        packageB
    groupB
        packageC
        packageD
    packageE
    packageF
```

Each package contains both a `src` and a `dist` folder.

I am looking for the best command to make each package compile to its respective `dist` directory.

## Ideal solution

In order of preference, what I am looking for is:

1. A single `tsconfig.json` file at the root and a command to watch (and compile) everything in their respective `dist` folders.
2. A `tsconfig.json` file for each package, specifying the `outDir` and `srcDir` folders and a command to watch (and compile) everything in their respective `dist` folders.

## My solution so far

I am not aware of any specific typescript way to face this, so the way I'd do it right now is using bash:

```
function dev_packages () {
  dir=`pwd`

  # list all folders in `/packages`
  find ./packages -type d | while read d; do
    # exclude `.../node_modules` folders
    dirname=$dir/$d
    if [[ $dirname != *"node_modules"* ]]; then
      # if contains a `tsconfig.json` 
      if [ -f "$dirname/tsconfig.json" ]; then
        echo '\n'$fg[yellow]'watching '$dirname'...'$reset_color
        cd $dirname && tsc -w
      fi
    fi
  done
}

dev_packages
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have main `tsconfig.json` at the project root and separated `tsconfig.json` files in package directory with folowing content:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: ok, but how do I `tsc -w` all of the packages, avoiding to `cd` into each dir and running the command?

Comment: in each `package.json` configure the same command like `build` and run `lerna run build`

Comment: for example, use yarn workspaces and https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-all-workspaces instead of lerna

Comment: hey, not bad -- one could also specify the config file, out dir, and src dir from the command line, thus avoiding the creation of many copies of the sale `tscofing.json` file all over. I'll play around with it. Meanwhile, you should post this as an answer!

Comment: throws an `Error: No workspaces`. Apparently, the main package.json should have a `workspaces` entry with a path to all of the updated packages. I think it's too much overhead.